# I want to publish my research framework for quantitative finance

Tags: fx, backtesting, research

I have spent numerous months writing a framework for testing and researching for strategies, I now want to publish this framework with hopes of possibly marketing myself. It includes quandl data as well as Oanda data. However I am not sure where to share this frame work. It is written in Java and has various math tools. I know I can publish it on github, and share it on my youtube which tends to get 300-600 views per video. I could also share it on forexfactory (an fx trading forum). Not sure where else I could share it, any ideas Quant SE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also consider publishing on:

1. SSRN - http://www.ssrn.com/en/
2. Google+ - https://plus.google.com
3. CodeProject - http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/Submit.aspx